# Generate Constructor below properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I choose the Quick Action Generate Constructor... it defaults to putting the constructor above the properties/fields

[image]

But I want it to be below

[image]

I see the ctor snippet located here but it's not clear to me how to edit it (or if it even is the right file for this) to do what I want

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#\ctor.snippet
```

Comment: You insert that snippet into a file by typing `ctor` (the shortcut in that file) and hitting tab twice. Of course, if you were in the habit of doing that, there wouldn't be anything to do since it gets added wherever you typed `ctor` in the file, which is entirely under your control. Not sure the refactoring (from that menu) is as easy to change.

Comment: I think that's a workable alternative, however the `ctor` snippet then inserts an empty constructor. Is it possible for it to insert a constructor with all the public properties?

Comment: Not as a snippet, snippets are essentially copy-paste pieces of code. It's why the "generate constructor" is built into the compiler, because it needs to analyze your class and generate code based on that. In fact, the only snippet I do regularly use is `propdp` since it doesn't really require code analysis, it's just a large chunk of code you have to write over and over and over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I choose the Quick Action Generate Constructor... it defaults to putting the constructor above the properties/fields

As other's have mentioned, this is either a "code fix" and or "reformatting". You've already witnessed the default of this quick action as it inserts above your properties, this is because of where you're doing it from; it will insert it based on the current line/cursor location.

To do what you want:

1. Create a new line below your properties
2. Click the Quick Actions and then `Generate constructor...`

Here's a quick gif of it working on my end...

[image]

Comment: oh this is awesome! I didn't appreciate this quick action showed up when the cursor was on blank lines/not on the class name line! This is perfect

Comment: @Brad glad to be of help.

Comment: Thank you! So much time will be saved

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing there isn't a snippet, to access that type `ctor` in the code window followed by two `TAB` characters.

What you're doing there is a "code fix" built into the compiler itself, Roslyn. The code fix decides where it places the code (and unfortunately they decided to go with individual assignments instead of a single expression body tuple assignment). You have no chance of changing it yourself without building a custom compiler (which is not terribly difficult), but you can just make your own code fix for this if you want.

Comment: That makes sense that this isn't a snippet.  I'm not following what you mean by `unfortunately they decided to go with individual assignments instead of a single expression body tuple assignment`  though

Comment: Something unrelated, a cleaner way of writing your constructor is simply `MyClass(string prop1, string prop2) => (Prop1, Prop2) = (prop1, prop2);` which is something that the code fix doesn't do.

Comment: I do like that! That's all 95% of my constructors are.

Comment: It's also literally all the generate constructor code fix can generate, lists of property assignments with no extra logic. It would make sense to use the expression body tuple assignment route, or at least give the option to!

Comment: So the Code Fix to make this happen is not a quick SO answer it seems. It's quite an involved process, [like this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix).

Comment: No, it's not a quick answer, but it's not terribly difficult either -- I wrote 3 of them already. And it's definitely a good tool to have in your belt, especially since the new .Net5 source generators are built on top of the same API as Roslyn code fixes and semantic analyzers!